# Uniform Continuity of $x^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Assume all the standards, such as $f:\mathbb R→\mathbb R$ and all that other jargon. I guess it doesn't really matter, but my main question is why isn't $f(x)=x^2$ uniformly continuous. I know if we restrict the domain to some subset $D\subset \mathbb R$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $D$, but not on the entire domain of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Vocabulary matters. What does uniform mean? It means whatever bound you find must be true independent of where you are, hence uniform. That cannot be the case for $x^2$ which gets steeper and steeper at a specific rate (although this is a heuristic and some functions that get steeper and steeper are still uniformly continuous, like $\sqrt{x}$)

Comment: One fact: $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$, then it cannot exceed a linear function, i.e. $\vert f (x)\vert \leqslant a \vert x \vert + b$ for some determined $a, b \in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of interpretations of what uniform continuity is. That's what makes it so useful, similar to how a matrix is useful due to the many interpretations (e.g. linear transformation, 2D array of information, vector of vectors, etc.).

One of the best analytical interpretations of uniform continuity can be found within the definition of continuity. For a function $f$ to be continuous at a point $x_0$, you obviously need to fix $\epsilon > 0$ and find (or prove there exists) a specific $\delta>0$ where $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$. In other words, you must find (or prove there exists) a special function $N:(0,\infty) \times D \rightarrow (0,\infty) $, where $N(\epsilon,x_0)=\delta$. This function (often called the [*modulus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity)) maps any $\epsilon$ and $x_0$ to some $\delta$ that satisfies that continuity predicate. For example, in order to prove $x^2$ is continuous at $x_0$, you are (whether you like it or not) forced to find (or prove there exists) such a function. I think for $x^2$, we can say $N(\epsilon,x_0)=\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{1+2|_0|})$. The modulus exists, so $x^2$ is continuous. Yay.

But what about uniform continuity? Note that $N$ is a function that depends on $\epsilon$ and $x_0$. If you vary $x_0$, the value of $N$ will change. If you can find a modulus that does not depend on $x_0$, as in if you vary $x_0$, then the value of $N$ doesn't change, then your function is uniformly continuous. You cannot do this for $x^2$. Any modulus you find, you will see that $x_0$ crops up somewhere in the definition (like the example I wrote). Showing this is true is kinda difficult obviously. You usually have to use a proof by contradiction.

I like to interpret moduli as a sort of quantization of continuity. Some functions are more "continuous" than others. How can you measure continuity? The modulus serves as a good way of doing that.

For a more geometric interpretation of uniform continuity means, I suggest checking out the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity) on it.

Comment: I like this, it's an interesting way to think about it in a way they haven't presented in my intro to analysis course. I don't think they would though. But it makes sense, and seems to be a more abstract way to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically because the slope of your curve is unbounded as $|x|\to\infty$. Given, say, $\epsilon=1$, at $x=0$ the corresponding $\delta$ in the limit definition is just 1 but at $x=2$  such $\delta$ is not good enough and you need say $\delta=0.2$ which in turn is not enough at $x=10$, etc. This lack of a universal $\delta$ is the reason why your function is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: After sitting with it and staring at it a bit longer, I understand what you're saying and it makes complete sense. Looking at the definition, $\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta$. A single $\delta$ for any $\epsilon$ one could think of, at some position on the domain of $x^2$ this $\delta$ fails to meet the $\epsilon$ condition.

Comment: That is exactly right. But as Spencer Kreisler mentioned you should be careful with this geometric intuition since functions like $x\to\sqrt{x}$ also become “vertical “ at some point, in this case $x=0$ but they are uniformly continuous nonetheless. There is a whole spectrum of moduli of continuity that guarantee uniform continuity but allow for infinite slopes.

Comment: Actually any continuous function on a compact domain is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

How do you show that a function $f:\mathbb R→\mathbb R$ is not uniformly continuous?

Since you have such a 'clean' domain, there is an easy (necessary) test that must be passed in order for $f$ to be uniformly continuous.

Define a sequence $a_n = f(n) - f(n-\frac{1}{n})$. 
If the function $f$ is  uniformly continuous then the sequence $a_n$ converges to $0$.

For $f(x) = x^2$,

$\tag 1 a_n = n^2 - (n - \frac{1}{n})^2 = 2 - \frac{1}{n^2}  $

and therefore

$\tag 2 {\displaystyle \lim _{n\to +\infty}} a_n = 2$

We conclude that $f(x) = x^2$ is not uniformly continuous.